# How do i make this in one row?

Tags: c#, combobox

How do i do this in one statement? I tried making them in one statement by removing the `;` and by adding a `+` inbetween but it didn't work. `sName` and `sRealname` are strings.

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(sName);
comboBox1.Items.Add(sRealname);
```

Edit: Sorry for the confusion. I need the text on the comboBox to show in 1 line from both sName and sRealname, but i need the code for each string seperated because if else the code breaks

Comment: see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why is it so important to do this in one line? You have wrong priorities.

Comment: Note that you're trying to do this in one *statement*, not one *line*. You could just place these two statements on one line if you wanted to, but that wouldn't be what you intended.

Comment: Seems he is looking for `sName + " " + sRealname`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: You can put anything in a method, is that one statement? I don't understand why OP needs this. Well, if `sName` and `sRealname` were already (large) collections, but in this case two statements for two variables is readable and concise enough.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I don't dispute that at all, the way it is now is clearer than using `AddRange`. I'm talking semantics: the way he has it now are two statements on two lines. He could just put both statements on the same line and his requirement of "how do I do this in one line" would be met, but he'd still have his two statements. It's nitpicking, but it's never too early to use proper terminology.

Comment: @UweKeim: Your comment is the answer. _" I need the text on the comboBox to show in 1 line from both sName and sRealname"_

Comment: @TimSchmelter OK, let's give it a try... :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `AddRange`:

```
 comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[]{sName, sRealname});
```

Comment: a bit shorter: 
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new []{sName, sRealname});

Comment: Doesn't show in 1 row in the combobox tho, the sRealname shows in a second row (below sName).

Comment: @user3024598 it's confusing here, looks like you want to show all the strings in **1 item**, not 1 row, there is not row here and *one line* is the nearest meaning to *one row* like as you described, if so see the other answer for the solution which is very simple **unless you also want some special format**.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I need the text on the comboBox to show in 1 line from both sName and sRealname, but i need the code for each string seperated because if else the code breaks.

Comment: @UweKeim only if you have the wrong types. As far as I know, these are strings and the compiler can infers it

Answer (score 4):

As [suggested by Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305068/how-do-i-make-this-in-one-row#comment30298473_20305068), I guess that you are looking for something like this:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add( sName + " " + sRealname );
```

Or, to make it more readable to me:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add( string.Format( "{0} {1}", sName, sRealname );
```

You could read on MSDN about [string concatenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx) or about the [`string.Format` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).